# Adding controls to CefSharp v51 (such as the URL bar, back, refresh)

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have CefSharp in a C# form for an important project, and I want to add navigation bars. I've Googled around, but nothing comes up. I've tried the following code:

```
browser.back();
Cef.browser.back();
CefSettings.back();
```

None of them do anything besides show error codes in the Visual Studio error console.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a basic working example. `v51` is old and no longer supported. Version `v71` is the current supported version. You can find the `API Docs` at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/

Comment: I know v51 is unsupported nowadays, but it's the only version I can get running without errors.

Comment: Try the `MinimalExample`, if the build fails on first attempt, close the **solution** then reopen it. Then build again.